# Unable to convert MVC3 web app to MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to upgrade my MVC3 web app to MVC 5 since I lost intellisense in VS2013

I am trying to upgrade from ASP.NET MVC 3 to 5 using the NuGet Package Manager.

PM> Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.1

But this command fails. Does anyone has the steps to converting MVC 3 to MVC 5?

I tried to follow this but it doesn't have all the steps:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-5/how-to-upgrade-an-aspnet-mvc-4-and-web-api-project-to-aspnet-mvc-5-and-web-api-2

Thanks for helping.

```
Install failed. Rolling back...
Install-Package : Could not install package 'Microsoft.AspNet.Razor 3.1.2'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
'.NETFramework,Version=v4.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For 
more information, contact the package author.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc -Version 5.1.1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: You will probably need to change the target framework of the project to 4.5 from the project settings.

Comment: That didn't do anything. I still get same error.

Comment: This is now resolved. One of the project was still using 4.0.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted.